# How to make a Website and API REST with Laravel with the same Controllers?

Tags: php, rest, laravel, web-applications, routes

I'm really new in Laravel Framework, I want to develop a Web Application that also has their own API Rest, but I don't know which is the best way to do it.

I want that the Controllers and methodos could be the sames for a Web opperation and for a API REST operation, for example for the Module of Users if I make a request like this:

http://myproject.com/userRegister/

Then the web shows me a view HTML with a form for user registration, but if I call a request like this:

http://myproject.com/api/userRegister/

Then the response will be a JSON with the Form data that I need for register the user.

I want that both of them use the UserRegisterController and the same method for example : "formRegister", all of this for avoid repeat bussines logic in differents methods.

Any idea of what is the best way to do this? I researched and some people recommend make all the services with JSON responses and parse with AngularJS or similar, but I don't want that, I want only use Laravel with HTML.

Comment: You would be much better off keeping them as separate controllers, but having them implement the same repository.

Answer (score 4):

Let the same controllers handle api and web requests is not the best decision. Sooner or later this logic will lead to the mess in your code.

Do not forget to keep your controllers as thin as possible and move most of your logic to models, services and repositories. This will help you to have two standalone controllers versions that will have as less code as possible.

But if you still want to combine them you can use `\Request::acceptsJson()` `\Request::acceptsHtml()` methods to determine what type of request you have.

Comment: but having them separated will result in too much redundant code

Comment: No, if you keep your controllers as tight as possible (and you have to do it btw).